# python - how to render a firebase dict in flask

Tags: python, dictionary, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database

I'm experimenting [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase), trying to pull some data from Firebase and render them in flask. This is how my data looks in firebase [database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HnJb.png)

In flask-python, retrieving the data and passing to render_template like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
all_post = db.child("post").get().val()
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(all_post.items()):
    dict = value
    print(dict)
return render_template('home.html', post=dict)
```

At this point, dict looks like this from the print statement above

```
{'postTitle': 'Second title', 'postBody': 'Second tyext'}
{'postTitle': 'Title of my post', 'postBody': 'Body of my post'}
```

And in my flask/jinja template, i'm looping the dict trying to render the data which is like a blog post, where i'm trying to display every blog title and it's body text in the database

```
{% for key, value in dict.items() %}
            <h2>{{ key }}</h2>
            <P>{{ value }}</P>
    {% endfor %}
```

The error I get when trying to render like above gives:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'items' of 'dict' object needs an argument
```

What is the best way to go about it, or where did I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError: descriptor 'items' of 'dict' object needs an argument

The error is because you're trying to do `dict.items()`. As in trying to call `items()` on the built-in dictionary data structure and not the name you created. The problem being that `dict` is not called `dict` in the template. It's called `post` in the template.

If you take a look at:

```
render_template('home.html', post=dict)
```

You're saying `post=dict`. Thus change:

```
{% for key, value in dict.items() %}
```

Into:

```
{% for key, value in post.items() %}
```

> however it rendered just one post and I have two post in the database

That's because you're looping through the posts, always assigning the current post to `dict`. So you'll always end up seeing the last post.

Instead you could do something like this:

```
posts = []
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(all_post.items()):
    posts.append(value)
    print(value)
return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for key, value in post.items() %}
        <h2>{{ key }}</h2>
        <P>{{ value }}</P>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks much, that was a silly and I changed to post.items() however it rendered just one post and I have two post in the database.

Comment: my looping is still not right I guess, would you take a look please

Comment: Your updated answer answered my question, i've marked it answered. Thanks much!